# Grab checkbox values and put them inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the JS code below. My target is to make a total of all selected checkbox attributes called "price-data" and display the total sum inside `<h4 "id="totalDisplay"` using `append()`.

I also need to add an array collection of each checkbox value, which is now 102 and 103. And whole things will be updated as per checkbox selection. I mean h4 display value and array collection value both will be updated in real time as per user checkbox selection. The `valueCollections` variable is for storing array values. I am new to jQuery, that's why I have no idea how to make the total sum and store array values actually. Ask any question you may have. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valueCollections[];
  $(".checkbox").on("click", function() {
    $('[price-data]').each(function() {
      $("#totalDisplay").append("<span class=\"label label-warning\">Total price: 70.50</span>");
    });
    $("#submitData").on("click", function() {
      $.post("/Controller/Method", {
        vales: valueCollections
      }).done(function(data) {
        //whatever goes here
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" price-data="50.50" value="102">option1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" price-data="20" value="103">option2</label>
</div>
<h4 id="totalDisplay"></h4>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="submitData">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collect `price-data` in an `array` and value on another then if `checkbox` is `checked` sum price and show checked `checkbox`. see below:

```js
var valueCollections = [];
var priceCollections = [];

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
  var priceData = $(this).attr('price-data');
  var val = $(this).val();

  // get checked

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    valueCollections.push(val); // push if checked
    priceCollections.push(priceData);
  } else {
    valueCollections.splice($.inArray(val, valueCollections), 1); // remove if not checked
    priceCollections.splice($.inArray(priceData, priceCollections), 1);
  }

  // sum array

  var sum = eval(priceCollections.join("+"))
  $('#totalDisplay').html(sum);

  console.log(valueCollections);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="totalDisplay">
</h4>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" price-data="50.50" value="102">option1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" price-data="20" value="103">option2</label>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="submitData">Submit</button>
```

Comment: great job man! thanks for your afford. i learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 0):

I made [a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Arrow891dev/7som3n1r/1/), but you have to improve it, for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-set">

</div>

<div id = "result">

</div>
```

Js:

```
var id = "";
for(i=1 ; i<8 ;i++){
    id="checkbox_"+i;
    $('.checkbox-set').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+ id +'" value="Click on me"/> <label for="'+id+'">Click on me</label> <br/> ');
}
var selected = [];


$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {        
        $(this).each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
        $("#result").html(selected);
        });
    }
    if(!this.checked) {
         const index = selected.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         var tt= selected.splice(index, 1);
             $("#result").html(selected);
    }
})
```

it's just a sample and not a full code, I hope you participate in it and do some efforts to achieve what you need :)